# UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification vs application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:

Tags: ios, nsnotifications

In UIViewController I register for **UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification** notification.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(btnContinuePressed:) 
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification 
                                               object:nil];
}
```

I want to execute `btnContinuePressed:` only if the application was resumed in a normal way - clicking the icon or opening via multitasking menu.

Method `btnContinuePressed:` should not be executed when the application was opened using URL scheme. Opening via URL scheme is handled in AppDelegate using custom notification:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"didOpenViaUrl" 
                                                        object:url];
    return YES;
}
```

Bottom line: notification `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` should not be triggered if `didOpenViaUrl` was.

Comment: Did you see this question / answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6037529/651651. seems promising. To me subscribing to WillEnterForeground inside a ViewController seems risky. I don't think you can be sure, that the VC is still in memory at that point. You might not get any notification at all in the worst case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple word you can not make difference them but you can do a tricky way to achieve by creating a BOOL property in your appDelegate code which will tell you from where the application has been opened I think!