# If application is in background state and launch on locanotification tap Which methods called in appdelegate

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification, appdelegate

In my app I am using uilocalnotifications. Every thing is ok but one thing. I need to show notifications's alertbody. If app is in foreground state it's fine, but if app is at background state and notification occurs, when i tap on that didReceiveLocalNotification doesn't get called. Obviously didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is also don't called at that time. So what should i do to handle the notification. I am using ios7 and xcode5. Thanks very much in advance if you could help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an app which is not in the foreground, the local notification can subsequently be found in the

`-applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif =
        [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (localNotif) {
        //Handle local notification here.
    }
```

You can read Apple's documentation for handling notifications [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html).

If the app is currently in memory, you can check it's state in the following way:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif
{
    if (app.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive )
    {
        NSLog(@"app not running");
    }
    else if(app.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive )
    {
        NSLog(@"app running");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks akashg for instant reply. But this method doesn't called. Because the app is already launched.

Comment: Check for further clarity here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136333/test-if-app-did-become-active-from-a-uilocalnotification

Comment: The answer with the maximum vote-ups on that page should help.

Comment: I've checked but when i debug didReceiveLocalNotification doesn't get called as i mentioned in question.

Comment: Is this happening in iOS 6 as well?

Comment: I don't know. But i am using ios7. I am debugging using breakpoints. When the app is at background state and notification is raised didReceiveLocalNotification doesn't call.

Comment: You need to check whether you app is in active state or not. if its in active state then simply return otherwise perform some action. 
if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive )
    {
        return;
    }
else
{
   //perform action
}

Comment: Please add some code related to your implementation of UILocalNotification

Comment: Bundle of Thanks. I got it

Comment: Muhammad: How did you resolve this? I'm experiencing the same thing that `didReceiveLocalNotification:` is not called after the application wakes from inactive state.

Comment: @MarkusRautopuro: see the first part of the answer. if app is killed and you tap on notification the '-applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions' get called. otherwise 'didReceiveLocalNotification'. edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

if application is closed and notification is raised then for that you have to write below code in appdidfinishlaunching method

```
// Handle launching from a notification
    UILocalNotification *objLocalNotif =
    [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (objLocalNotif)
    {
        NSLog(@"At the time of launching Recieved Notification %@",objLocalNotif);
        //Do your stuff here
    }
```

If application is in background and when any local notification is raised the following method of app delegate get called.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
    // Handle the notificaton when the app is running

    NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",notif);
    //do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write your code in the below method

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

it will be called when you open your application again which has not been terminated fully but still running in background

Comment: How do you know that the application comes foreground from tapping a local notification, and not just from tapping the app icon?