# How to send a silent Push Notification payload

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I just want to know how I can determine what action to do on a silent push:

This is the `aps` that I sent to the client:

```
"aps": {
    "content-available": 1
}
```

My problem now is when I add `type: "Order_Update"` to determine that the silent push is for the Order Update to display an alert notification.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

There are a few options for it! Let's take a small ride to understand all the different payloads and their usage.

---

**Simple Payload**

Displayed in Notification Center : Yes

Wakes app to perform background task : No

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You received simple notification!",
        "badge" : 1,
        "sound" : "default"
    }
}
```

---

**Payload With Custom Notification Sound**

Displayed in Notification Center : Yes

Wakes app to perform background task : No

`Step 1` : Add custom notification sound file (.wav or .aiff extensions only. e.g. notification.wav) in your app bundle.

`Step 2` : Configure your payload as shown below to play your custom sound

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "It's a custom notification sound!",
        "badge" : 1,
        "sound" : "notification.wav"
    }
}
```

---

**Notification With Custom Payload**

Displayed in Notification Center : Yes

Wakes app to perform background task : No

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "It's a notification with custom payload!",
        "badge" : 1,
        "content-available" : 0         
    },
    "data" :{
        "title" : "Game Request",
        "body" : "Bob wants to play poker",
        "action-loc-key" : "PLAY"
    },

}
```

Here the `data` dictionary holds custom information whatever you want. It will also display as normal notification with the alert message "It's a notification with custom payload!".

---

**Normal Silent Notification**

It will not a show an alert as a notification bar; it will only notify your app that there is some new data available, prompting the app to fetch new content.

Displayed in Notification center : No

Awake app to perform background task : Yes

```
{
    "content-available" : 1
}
```

---

**Silent Notification With Custom Payload**

Here comes the magic to show a notification alert as well awake your app in background for a task! (Note: only if it's running in background and has not been killed explicitly by the user.)
Just add the extra parameter `"content-available" : 1` in your payload.

Displayed in Notification Center : Yes

Wakes app to perform background task : Yes

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "Notification with custom payload!",
        "badge" : 1,
        "content-available" : 1
    },
     "data" :{
        "title" : "Game Request",
        "body" : "Bob wants to play poker",
        "action-loc-key" : "PLAY"
     }
}
```

---

Use any of these payloads according to your app requirements. For `background app refresh` refer to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22). I hope this gives you all the necessary information. Happy coding :)

Comment: Great answer but I think you miss data parameter in Notification with custom payload section.

Comment: Thanks @LiborZapletal for noting it, i have updated answer.

Comment: According the Apple documentation the "content-available' must be inside the "aps".  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1  Why you use it outside of the "aps"?

Comment: @makkasi yes you are right, it should be under "aps", I have updated answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: For the Silent notification, can I have client-side logic to decide whether to display the notification or not?

Comment: No you cant have client side logic as its decided by System based on payload , but based on payload "content-available" you can take some action

Comment: I can't see any difference between 3rd example (Notification with custom payload) and 5th(Silent Notification with custom payload) example push dictionary. Why it causes different background execution behaviour, NO for the 3rd and YES for the 5th? They are both bring app to Background State and execute code, if some project settings enabled.

Comment: @AlexanderLarionov I believe that the 3rd example should say "0" for content available, and "1" for the 5th example.That's the flag that adds the "silent" feature

Comment: @shadowmoses you are right, modified answer as suggested

Comment: I try to use the example "Silent notification with custom payload" but if the application is in foreground the system notification appear, i think if the alert is present it isn't silent notification. it is true?

Comment: @DipenPanchasara thanks for the insight. When you say wakes app to perform background task, does the app trigger "applicationDidFinishLauchingWithOptions:" upon receiving the silent push?

Comment: @rach No, it just invokes background task block which you have implemented for remote push-notification. It awakes app for particular task and suspends again, you can't perform long running task there. Hope it would be helpful :)

Comment: @DipenPanchasara @rach It does call `applicationDidFinishLauchingWithOptions`. In our case the app is killed from the apps tray. But when a push notification with `content-available 1` payload is received.  `applicationDidFinishLauchingWithOptions` is invoked. Another reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34728550/1045672

Comment: is sound parameter with 'defalut' is required to play ios custom sound ?

Answer (score 4):

As i understand, you want extra data inside payload, so you can identify what push notification type is,or what action need to be handled.

For that edit your payload as:

```
 $body = array(
    'content-available' => 1,
    'sound' => ''
    );  

$payload = array();
$payload['aps'] = $body;
$payload['action'] = 'order_update';
```

Then in your iOS Code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{


    NSString *action = userInfo["action"];


    if([userInfo[@"aps"][@"content-available"] intValue]== 1 && [action isEqualToString:@"order_update") //order update notification
    {
        //handle Your Action here
        return;
    }


}
```

Hope this solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Please also check `apns-push-type` (Required for watchOS 6 and later; recommended for macOS, iOS, tvOS, and iPadOS) The value of this header must accurately reflect the contents of your notification’s payload. If there is a mismatch, or if the header is missing on required systems, APNs may return an error, delay the delivery of the notification, or drop it altogether.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns