# IOS Silent Push Notification to send custom Key/Value

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I have a use case where I need to send a custom key/value pair. Please see the example below:

```
 {
    "aps":{"content-available":1},
    "test_data":{"Name":"Vinay"}
    }
```

I have done this exercise at my end but I am not able to send this, Also I have not find a clear proof where Apple restrict this. Can anybody support me on this context.

Comment: Apple _don't_ restrict this - a silent push should be perfectly valid. Can you send push messages with content to your app?

Comment: as mentioned above, can we send custom key/value to device to do some action based upon that value. In the above case it is test_data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no issue with this until and unless you have configured well. For configuration details refer apple documentation. I have created a POC and it is working perfectly fine and I noticed only once issue if we are utilising Artisian SDK(older version) so it will swallow your payload and that is the only Issue what I was facing.

**To be precise:**
We can invoke app in background without notifying user by using silent notification. And we can send our custom data as shown in below example:

{"Data":"Vinay","aps": {"content-available": 1}}

Answer (score 4):

Yes Apple authorize it the silent push. In fact, Apple explain how to to so:

> To support silent remote notifications, add the remote-notification value to the UIBackgroundModes array in your Info.plist file. To learn more about this array, see UIBackgroundModes.

And, in *Configuring a Silent Notification*:

> The aps dictionary can also contain the content-available property. The content-available property with a value of 1 lets the remote notification act as a silent notification. When a silent notification arrives, iOS wakes up your app in the background so that you can get new data from your server or do background information processing. Users aren’t told about the new or changed information that results from a silent notification, but they can find out about it the next time they open your app.

-

> For a silent notification, take care to ensure there is no alert, sound, or badge payload in the aps dictionary. If you don’t follow this guidance, the incorrectly-configured notification might be throttled and not delivered to the app in the background, and instead of being silent is displayed to the user.

*Update:*

But it seems to be impossible to have a totally silent push AND custom data. It's not well documented, but take a look at this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36327058/2846494

**Source:** 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW6

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36327058/2846494

Comment: Thanks for details, But can you Please answer the question what I asked. Can we send customer key values in silent push or not. Thanks a Lot.

Comment: as mentioned above, can we send custom key/value to device to do some action based upon that value. In the above case it is test_data

Comment: Ho, In fact, that's not possible to have totally silent notification AND custom data. It's not well documented, but have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36327058/2846494