# FCM silent push notification structure for iOS?

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, ios10, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need example of notification payload for silent notification, I tried this below structure, but it's not working

```
{ 
    "notification" : {
        "body" : " Survey list updated",
        "content-available:" : true,
        "data" : {
            "isNewUpdateAvailable" : "easysurvey.survey_list_updated"
            }
        },
        "to" : "f6PwToRUxk0:APA91bG7bSWoKsjHXVmXaiDEnFXA2x2jEOMSO6eGCqPv1fRd-dctNLDEabRq-0So_obuPGFqOFTSLJl5FFyuOuXKBXh-n89BmzzXenRTxoirY9Y1c6-J9MxpDp0ojHL2xm1law0V6gg3"
}
```

Using this structure, I am able to receive notifications, but it's not silent & doesn't wake the app.
i need solution for firebase notification & on iOS 10,
i am following same [firebase sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift) code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Silent Push Notification Payload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36323903/silent-push-notification-payload)

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov actually this question is regarding, FCM

Comment: in android you have to use the "data" to receive apps in the background, otherwise you need to have the app in foreground. Don't know what ios is like

Comment: `content_available` is a top level field, so make it a sibling of the notification payload.

Comment: @sheshnath Hi. Do post relevant code snippets. Not entirely familiar with the changes for iOS 10. Have you seen the notes specific for iOS 10 in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client)?

Comment: @AL. just for additional information i mentioned iOS 10, even i don't know any specific for iOS 10

Comment: Sorry. What I meant was there are some specific notes in the documentation intended for iOS 10 implementations. Have you gone through them before?

Comment: No as of now, going through it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i got the answer, write payload structure in this way.

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "title":"mytitle",
      "body":"mybody",
      "url":"myurl"
   },
   "notification":{  
      "title":"mytitle",
      "body":"mybody",
      "content_available": true
   },
   "to":"DEVICE_FCM_TOKEN"
}
```

this may help someone.
if you wish to test FCM notification using POSTMAN Api client, use "key=YOUR_SERVER_KEY"
[image]