# How can i receive Messages in voip?

Tags: objective-c, firebase-cloud-messaging, token, message, voip

How can I receive Messages in voip? I can get the Voip Token!

I'm writing in Objective C:

I have searched around the internet but can't find any solutions! All I found is Swift, but can't get the token in Swift.  In Objective C I can get token but not get Messages from a line.

```
apn push "<Token>" -c backgroundfetch.pem -m "Hello"
```

How can I popup a Messages in Objective C? Here is my code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@import PushKit;
@import UserNotifications;

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


NSString *fcmToken = @"";

// Trigger VoIP registration on launch
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [self voipRegistration];
    return YES;
}

// Register for VoIP notifications
- (void) voipRegistration {
    dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    // Create a push registry object
    PKPushRegistry * voipRegistry = [[PKPushRegistry alloc] initWithQueue: mainQueue];
    // Set the registry's delegate to self
    voipRegistry.delegate = self;
    // Set the push type to VoIP
    voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:PKPushTypeVoIP];
}

- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didUpdatePushCredentials:(PKPushCredentials *)credentials forType:(NSString *)type{
    if([credentials.token length] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"voip token NULL");
        return;
    }
    
    NSLog(@"PushCredentials: %@", credentials.token);
}


// Handle incoming pushes
- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload forType:(NSString *)type {
    // Process the received push
    NSLog(@"Get");
}



@end
```

My `info.plist`:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>voip</string>
    <string>audio</string>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Could you explain me the need of implementation of VOIP push in the application? Based on your requirement I can suggest you the best way.

Comment: hello, my need is to trigger an appilcation in my phone. So i will like to 'wake up' the phone and exucute some code statements that i have made. My idea is: i have a token, and send to a specific device, and then run the statements!

Comment: Well in this case you can send a silent push notification and on received of notification you can execute code. But remember your app will not open in foreground. it will remain in background only.

Comment: How do I send a "silent push notification"? Which code do I have to use to send a "silent push notification"?

Answer (score 0):

In your case the solution is to send a silent push notification. Once the silent push notification arrives, execute your code with background task.

Here is the good explanations for sending a silent push notification.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36327058/9106403

Comment: Hej thanks for the link, but "content-available" will not wake up the iPhone (When the actual app is Inactive. Not in background mode), and turn into background mode.

Comment: so you want to visible the push ?

Comment: I want to start an inactive application.

Comment: Means you want your app start in background and silent push notification is best for that. It will not notify the use that push receive and you can execute your code in background.

Comment: I mean in inactive mode and start the app up and execute code.

Comment: Silent push will not notify the user while normal push will notify the user, but in both case you can execute your code in background. if app already running then you can execute your code on main thread.

Comment: how can i go from suspended to backgorund mode? while ("content-available" : 1) not working.

Comment: Other app will (execute code) ininactive/suspeded.eg: 1. (DSCloud Synology) 2. (Dropbox) in app store. Other app will run some code

Comment: It should open iOS. Make sure you have enable this settings : https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*6w-RS_v0zcNtHj7r_OXp3A.png

Comment: I have the settings in my "Capabillites". Thanks for your replay

Comment: Do you think some problem with (Xcode or IOS) issue?

Comment: Maybe. update your question with push handle code. I will look into that.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you main with "push handler code". did you main "Push notifcation payload"? Xcode console?

Comment: hello, i found this here https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/85077 i think some issue with Xcode