# Get only Badge count in notification with out Notification Alert

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, badge

All,

We have a notification tab in our app, where we are displaying all the Notifications, We are displaying the count on the Badge, Whenever user view the notification, we are decrementing the Badge count. Now we have a use case where the user can log in in multiple devices unless the user goes into the application we cannot update the Badge.

Now we want to send Notification for an only Badge number, Is it possible to do that without triggering an alert.

In our app, we have other notifications as well with message display for we cannot register only Badge number.

Answer (score 0):

you can send a silent push notification so that the client app can remove the badge count without user concern.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36327058/2815002